# Sort the fields in a struct based on value

Tags: matlab, sorting, struct

Say I have a struct:

```
MyStruct.a = 12;
MyStruct.b = 22;
MyStruct.c = 32;
```

Can I modify it so that the fields are ordered based on their value:

```
MyStruct
c: 32
b: 22
a: 12
```

The `orderfields` methods allow ordering of the struct based on the field name or other structures/cell arrays, but not by value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
% Define initial structure:

myStruct.a = 12;
myStruct.b = 22;
myStruct.c = 32;

% Find desired order of values, rather than fieldnames:

[ ~,sortIdx ] = sort( structfun( @(x) x, myStruct ), 'descend' );

% Apply orderfields():

mySortedStruct = orderfields( myStruct, sortIdx )
```

Answer (score 1):

`orderfields` has [a syntax](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/orderfields.html#d117e1002539) where it orders based on a permutation array. The [second output of `sort`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html#d117e1328513) is a permutation array. Something like this should work:

```
[~,I] = sort(cell2mat(struct2cell(MyStruct)));
I = flip(I); % reverse ordering to get larger elements first
MyStruct = orderfields(MyStruct,I);
```

Comment: Does that order based on the field names? I need order based on values. But 
 I see the general idea, @RM25483 answer is similar and obtains the correct permutation array to order based on values.

Comment: @Mansoor: You're right, fixed (using different syntax from the other answer).